# Linear combination of the components of a vector in the sum of two vector subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

For context, I’m taking a first-year undergraduate course in Linear Algebra. I’m aware that given a Vector space $V$ the sum of two subspaces of $V$ is also a subspace. I came across a question that, given a vector space $V$, defines the set $$W_{v}= \{\alpha v: \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ for $v \in V$. Then for $v_{1}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} ,v_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix} \in V$, I need to find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}=\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3: \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z = 0\}$$.

My approach involved defining $W_{v_1},W_{v_2}$:
$$W_{v_1} = \{kv_1: k\in\mathbb{R}\}\\W_{v_2} = \{rv_2: r\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
Then, I have the sum:
$$W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix} k\\k-r\\r\end{bmatrix}$$ at which point there should be a linear combination of the components that equals 0.
$$\alpha k+\beta (k-r) + \gamma r = 0 \\ \rightarrow(\alpha +\beta)k = (\beta - \gamma) r$$

At this point I was stuck on how to move forward as in my head $k,r \in\mathbb{R}$ can be any real numbers, so surely $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ would change for different choices of $k$ and $r$. Trivially, I could choose $\alpha,\beta,\gamma = 0$ which would satisfy the condition but I'm not sure if that's what the question is looking for. As I've been writing this out I pondered about making $$\alpha+\beta = 0\\\beta - \gamma = 0\\ \rightarrow \beta=-\alpha=\gamma$$ which would work for any two real numbers. Is this line of thinking correct?

The question hints that this is essentially asking me to find a subspace $W_{v_1} +W_{v_2}$ but it's not immediately clear to me how that is related.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, I think your 'line of thinking' is correct. You want to find $\alpha ,\beta, \gamma$ such that $(\alpha +\beta)k = (\beta - \gamma) r$ for any r and k. The values you suggested are exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3: \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z = 0\right\}$ for some fixed $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Note that if $m \ne 0$, then $$\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z = 0 \iff (m\alpha) x + (m\beta) y + (m\gamma) z = 0$$
so we get the same set $Q$ if we multiply the three values by the same non-zero constant.

Now, $W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}= Q$ requires that the solutions to $\alpha x + \beta y  + \gamma z = 0$ be *exactly* the points of $W_{v_1} + W_{v_2}$, no more, no less. So $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$ doesn't work, as all of $\Bbb R^3$ satisfies that equation, not just $W_{v_1} + W_{v_2}$.

Also in your work, note that properly $$W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}k\\k-r\\r\end{bmatrix} : k \in \Bbb R, r \in \Bbb R\right\}$$ as $W_{v_1}, W_{v_2}$ are sets, and so is their sum.

Now $W_{v_1}+W_{v_2} = Q$ is equivalent to $W_{v_1}+W_{v_2} \subseteq Q$ and $Q\subseteq W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}$.

The requirement that $W_{v_1}+W_{v_2} \subseteq Q$ give us that for *each* pair of values $k,r$, we have $$\alpha k+\beta (k-r) + \gamma r = 0$$
In particular, it holds for $k=1, r= 0$, giving $\alpha + \beta = 0$, and for $r = 1, k = 0$, giving $\gamma - \beta = 0$. So for $Q$ to contain the subspace, we must have
$$-\alpha = \beta = \gamma$$
And since scaling doesn't effect the set $Q$, this is as far as we can go in determining their values.

Conversely $Q\subseteq W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}$ requires that if $x,y,z$ satisfy
$-\gamma x + \gamma y +\gamma z = 0$, then there must be $k,r$ with $x = k, y = k - r, z = r$. I.e., that $y = x - z$. Or equivalently, that $-x + y + z = 0$. If $\gamma \ne 0$, this follows immediately by dividing it out. But if $\gamma = 0$, then there are solutions for $x,y,z$ for which $-x + y + z = 0$ does not hold.

So $W_{v_1}+W_{v_2}= Q$ if and only if $-\alpha = \beta = \gamma \ne 0$.

Comment: I should be clear - my reason for this is to fill in the gaps in your reasoning, pointing out exactly why the things you were unclear on are true. I am not disagreeing with your approach or calculations.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. This makes a lot more sense now.